# Displaying PDF from stream using Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I'm developing application using Node.js and Express. I have need to display PDF stored in GridFS. So I'm getting it as a stream and now I need to display it.(not download it but display on the fly) 
Can someone share some examples (both js and html code) how similar tasks can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Pdfkit:

```
sudo npm install pdfkit
```